# How to read a YUV420SP file format image?

Tags: android, image, yuv

Hey, I am using an application for obtaining the raw data from the image sensor on an Android device. The files I am getting out are in the YUV420SP format,and XnView does not supprt it. Does anyone knows which software I could use to get a proper image? (to convert it)

Comment: See android.media.MediaCodec use MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT = MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar